# Julian Date Conversion SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, julian-date

How to convert the Julian date to Gregorian Calendar date in SQL Server? Below are the cases:

1. 6 digit number - I have done the conversion and it is working fine
2. 5 digit number - I don't have any idea about how to convert this Julian date to normal date. I did search in Google websites, but each websites have different answers, so I am confused. Example data (47315, 45009, 69064, 99281, 98222, 98329)
3. If I have the value "0" in the Julian date column, then how to convert this value to Gregorian date?

Comment: This is very vague in its current form. Can you edit the question to point out a specific case you need to convert, and how the methods you found on Google didn't agree with what you expected?

Comment: Please add your table `CREATE` statement ;).

Comment: Are you supposed to count for the variances in how leap years are determined? What about the year that had 355 days when Julian calendars converted to gregorian for England and the easter US?

Answer (score 0):

That second scenario looks like YYJJJ format.

Converting it would look something like

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, CAST(RIGHT(yourdate, 3) AS integer) - 1, CONVERT(smalldatetime,'01/01/' + LEFT(yourdate, 2), 3)) AS converteddate
FROM <yourtable>
```